# Stash - tag pairs to set multiple variables at once - no results / no_results

Tags: stash

This one kept me busy for a while and I although could find similar questions none of the solutions worked.

Using template partials, gather the page content then send though (via embed) to a master wrapper template. This site has 'pages' where the URL should identify a unique entry, but EE tries it's best to show something, adding `require_entry` in the Channel tag should trigger `no_results` if an entry can't be found.

`{no_results}` works as expected when trying the `channel:entries` tag (below) outside of stash. Looking at stash docs, `unprefix` is specifically for this scenario. The below code **does** work.

```
{exp:stash:set
    name        = "st_page_content"
    parse_tags  = "yes"
    unprefix    = "my_prefix"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
            channel         = "channel_short_name"
            limit           = "1"
            require_entry   = "yes"
        }

    <p>{title}</p>

    {if my_prefix:no_results}<p>no results</p>{/if}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

But it **doesn't** work when stashing multiple variables between 1 stash tag pair. Eg. `no_results` is **not** stored in `st_page_content`:

```
{exp:stash:set
    name        = "st_page_content"
    parse_tags  = "yes"
    unprefix    = "my_prefix"
}

    {stash:st_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:st_entry_id}

    {stash:st_page_content}

        {exp:channel:entries
                channel         = "channel_short_name"
                limit           = "1"
                require_entry   = "yes"
            }

        <p>{title}</p>

        {if my_prefix:no_results}<p>no results</p>{/if}

        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/stash:st_page_content}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

EE 2.9.2
Stash 2.6.1 (Dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the example code in the question should work but it doesn't. Here's a solution. I understand why it does work, but it *seems* wrong.

```
{exp:stash:set
    name        = "st_page_content"
    parse_tags  = "yes"
    unprefix    = "my_prefix"
}

    {stash:st_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:st_entry_id}

    {stash:st_page_content}

        {exp:channel:entries
                channel         = "channel_short_name"
                limit           = "1"
                require_entry   = "yes"
            }

        <p>{title}</p>

        {if my_prefix:no_results}<p>no results</p>{/if}

        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/stash:st_page_content}

    {if stash_prefix:no_results}
        {stash:st_page_content}{redirect="404"}{/stash:st_page_content}
    {/if}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

If EE can't find an entry, anything **not** inside `no_results` is discarded. So all that's left inside the `stash:set` is:

```
{if stash_prefix:no_results}
    {stash:st_page_content}{redirect="404"}{/stash:st_page_content}
{/if}
```

And now `st_page_content` will store just the no_results content. It seems wrong to be setting the same variable twice but due to EEs parse order there's only ever one instance of `st_page_content`.

---

#### Update 15/03/11

After getting feedback from Mark, there's another solution, that's really not that different! https://twitter.com/croxton/status/573949167824953344

> that's one way to do it. But you should be able to use
>   {exp:stash:not_found} inside the first conditional to return your 404.

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp:stash:not_found%7D#advanced-example

I've tried this and it does **not** work:

```
{exp:stash:set
    name        = "st_page_content"
    parse_tags  = "yes"
    unprefix    = "my_prefix"
}

    {stash:st_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:st_entry_id}

    {stash:st_page_content}

        {exp:channel:entries
                channel         = "channel_short_name"
                limit           = "1"
                require_entry   = "yes"
            }

        <p>{title}</p>

        {if my_prefix:no_results}<p>no results</p>{/if}

        {/exp:channel:entries}

        {if stash_prefix:no_results}
            {exp:stash:not_found}
        {/if}

    {/stash:st_page_content}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

Putting the `{exp:stash:not_found}` in the first tag pair (`{stash:st_entry_id}`) doesn't work either.

But similar to my original solution wrapping `{exp:stash:not_found}` with the variable tag pair does work. This is exactly the same solution as using `{redirect="404"}` but maybe EEs redirect tag will cause problems in other circumstances.

Alternative solution:

```
{exp:stash:set
    name        = "st_page_content"
    parse_tags  = "yes"
    unprefix    = "my_prefix"
}

    {stash:st_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:st_entry_id}

    {stash:st_page_content}

        {exp:channel:entries
                channel         = "channel_short_name"
                limit           = "1"
                require_entry   = "yes"
            }

        <p>{title}</p>

        {if my_prefix:no_results}<p>no results</p>{/if}

        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/stash:st_page_content}

    {if stash_prefix:no_results}
        {stash:st_page_content}{exp:stash:not_found}{/stash:st_page_content}
    {/if}

{/exp:stash:set}
```